# Filter Feature Layer by bookmark in ArcGIS Instant App

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, feature-layer

I have an app built from the Instant App templates. It's using a webmap that has bookmarks set for certain areas of interest. The client I made the app for has asked if I'm able to filter the hosted feature layers that show up in the bookmark. Is that even possible?

For example, I have layers for public as well as private sustainable infrastructure projects. I have a handful of bookmarks labeled as public and private. But, sometimes the private features show up in the public bookmark, and vice versa. The best I can think of is to tell the user to turn on/off the layers they want to see using the the layer list because doing that is not intuitive.

I've never come across filtering by bookmark, so my question just might end up in the dust heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I still don't believe there is a way to do this directly, especially since it's an Instant App (i.e. I don't think you can obtain source code), I'll post the option of going the long way around.

If you have feature(s) that show up in a bookmark(s) and you don't want them to:

1. create a separate layer(s) for the feature(s) in Pro then share as a web layer
2. open your webmap
3. click the bookmark(s) where feature(s) is appearing
4. set the visibility range of the feature(s) so it doesn't fall within the bookmark(s) visibility range

This will at least work until the user decides to zoom in or out.